I have a legend in a fieldset that will not display
This code is formatted essentially identically to other fieldsets in a basic project i'm using to gain experience, but the legend won't display! The issue is not in my stylesheet as I removed it temporarily and the legend was still not visible.
\<fieldset\>
\<legend class="legend" for="radio"\>Which of the following do you think best describes    you?\</legend\>
\<div\>
\<label for="radio"\>\<input name="radio" type="radio" value="1" name="radio" checked\>I like to plan holidays several months or more in advance\</label\>
\</div\>
\<div\>
\<label for="radio"\>\<input name="radio" type="radio" value="2" name="radio"\>I usually plan holidays a few months in advance\</label\>
\</div\>
\<div\>
\<label for="radio"\>\<input name="radio" type="radio" value="3" name="radio"\>I usually plan holidays a few weeks in advance\</label\>
\</div\>
\</fieldset\>

enter image description here
Here's an example of another fieldset that is working fine in the same html doc (see image).
<fieldset>
<legend  class="legend" for="`your text`checkbox">Which of the following apply to you?     </legend>
<div>
<input type="checkbox" value="1"><label>I like lazy beach holidays</label>
</div>
<div>
<input type="checkbox" value="2"><label>I like exciting city breaks</label>
</div>
<div>
<input type="checkbox" value="3"><label>I like to visit cultaral attractions like museums</label>
</div>
<div>
<input type="checkbox" value="4"><label>I like to explore and experience local culture</label>
</div>
</fieldset>

enter image description here

Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be tested by others to provide an answer faster.

Your codes are escaped which are unnecessarily preventing the fieldset tag fromrendering properly
<fieldset>
<legend class="legend" for="radio">Which of the following do you think best describes    you?</legend>
<div>
<label for="radio"><input name="radio" type="radio" value="1" name="radio" checked>I like to plan holidays several months or more in advance</label>
</div>
<div>
<label for="radio"><input name="radio" type="radio" value="2" name="radio">I usually plan holidays a few months in advance</label>
</div>
<div>
<label for="radio"><input name="radio" type="radio" value="3" name="radio">I usually plan holidays a few weeks in advance</label>
</div>
</fieldset>

